# Image will not render on UITabBar Item iOS9

Tags: ios, image, uitabbar

This may or may not be a problem experienced because of iOS9.0.2. I have an image, .png file, that I am trying to set as one of my tab bar icons. I have no trouble setting other images for the icon but this particular icon will NOT set. Here's a screen shot:

[image: Tab bar icon in place]

You can see here that I clearly have an image set to the **UITabBar** tab, but when I run it on my iPhone, its completely invisible(not there). I'm assuming that there is something wrong with this **.png** file because I can easily set other images. What could be wrong here?

**EDIT**
Here's additional code I added to the AppDelegate.m file to ensure correct rendering mode.

```
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem4 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:3];
tabBarItem4.selectedImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"blah.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal ];
tabBarItem4.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"blah.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal ];
```

PS I've also programmatically added the image to the tabBar index through AppDelegate and it still does not appear. So please don't answer with a programmatic answer. It's not the problem

Comment: Did you try changing the setting of the image's rendering mode? You can do this either programatically or using your assets collection. I've had this kind of issue where the image was being rendered [incorrectly] in Template mode, thus not showing.

Comment: Using your assets collection? not sure what that is, also how would I do this programmatically to change the rendering mode? Im about to look up the problem.

Comment: You can add the image to your assets collection and change the default rendering mode from there, or in code you can use `[[UIImage imageNamed:@"blah.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]`. [Reference here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIImageRenderingMode).

Comment: Sorry one last question, where would this code go? Since the image itself is simply contained in Images folder and the image is set in the navigation controller?

Comment: Just use that piece of code where you set the tabBar image. It will return an UIImage. If you use the assets collection (which I find easier), you can set the rendering mode there changing the 'Render as' parameter ([example here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5z1C6.png)) and just select it on the tabBar using Storyboard.

Comment: I posted an answer with those instructions to formalise the question. Could you please mark it as accepted? :)

Answer (score 7):

UITabBar renders the image with `UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate`, which sometimes doesn't work if you haven't prepared the image correctly for this.

To use the original image, **set the image's rendering mode to 'original'**.

Programatically, just use UIImage's `imageWithRenderingMode:` method:

`tabBarItem.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"blah.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];`

If you are managing your images with XCAssets, select the image and change 'Render as' to 'original image' ([example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5z1C6.png)).